# necessary and sufficient condition on non-negative functions that insures the measure integral is finite

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $a \in X$ and $\mu$ be a measure defined on $2^{X}$ by
$$
\mu(E)= \begin{cases}1, & a \in E \\ 0, & a \notin E\end{cases}
$$
Write a simple necessary and sufficient condition on the non-negative functions $f$ that ensures that
$$
\int_{X} f d \mu<\infty
$$

**My attempt:**

We know that $\int_{X} f d \mu=\sup \left\{\int_{X} s d \mu=\sum y_{i} \mu\left(A_{i}\right) \mid s \text { simple }, s \geq 0, s \leq f\right\}$, so we want the supremum to be finite and for this I'm thinking that the functions should have a finite border but I'm not sure if it works!

Comment: $\int_X fd\mu=f(a)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But how is this a condition on $f$ itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum y_{i} \mu (A_{i}) =y_i$ if there $i$ is such that $a \in A_i$ and $0$ if there is no such $i$. Note that if $A_i$'s are disjoint there can be at most one $i$ for which $A \in A_i$. Hnece $\int s d\mu=s(a)$. From this it follows that $\int f d\mu=f(a)$ for all non-negative measurable functiosn $f$. Hence, the conditioin is $f(a) <\infty$.